# In Objective-C, how can I make this code efficient?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

```
[self.menuBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuBtn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuBtn4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuBtn5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuBtn6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu6.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.menuBtn7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu7.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This Code is very inefficient. But I think it can be efficient with `for`syntax. However I don't know how can I code `self.menuBtn%d` with `for`. In Objective-C, How can I code this?

Comment: try adding them in an array or assign tag to the button.

Comment: Is menuBtnx a property?

Comment: Inefficient? In what way?

Comment: By the way, since what you've done is essentially unrolling a `for` loop, your code can't be "more efficient" (as in "run faster"). Perhaps you meant "cleaner", "better structured", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This access the button properties dynamically so you don't need an array. This only works if the buttons have already been initialized (they are if they're `IBOutlets`)

```
NSString *imageName;
NSString *buttonName;
UIImage  *image;
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    //@autoreleasepool {

    imageName  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"menu%d", i];
    buttonName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"menuBtn%d", i];
    image      = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self valueForKey:buttonName];

    if (button)
        [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    /*
     If you needed to scale this to say 1000 images, you can uncomment the first 
     and last line in the for-loop which will automatically release the variables
     each iteration so the memory consumption doesn't spike.
   */
   //}
}
```

Comment: Setting the local vars to nil on this loop round, or to their new value in the next round doesn't change the timing of deallocation very much: the referenced objects should be deallocated the moment the reference is severed (either set to nil or another object), or am I mistaken?

Comment: @NicolasMiari You are probably right but I have had severe memory allocation issues with for-loops in the past, only with numbers in excess of 10000 but issues none the less

Comment: Better safe than sorry! ;)

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be to set the tag of all your buttons to some value (e.g. 100 + button number), then to try:

```
for (UIButton *aButton in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ((aButton.tag >= 100 and aButton.tag < 107))
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"menu%d.png",aButton.tag]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Why is tag between 100 and 200? He wants 1 through 7.

Comment: Just for scalability. Make the upper limit however many buttons you have.

Comment: This a bad idea. If you have a lot of subviews, you're unnecessarily accessing each and every subview. This increases memory consumption, decreases performance and will throw an exception if the subview is not actually a UIButton object.

Comment: Agreed, yours is better.

Comment: Just to be clear, it will only throw an exception if a subview with a tag in the given range is something other than a UIButton, not if _any_ subview is.

Answer (score 1):

First add the buttons to the array and the use for loop like this:

```
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuBtn1,menuBtn2,menuBtn3,menuBtn4,menuBtn5,menuBtn6menuBtn7,nil];
int i=1;
for(UIButton *aButton in array){
    [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"menu%d.png",i++]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *menubutton;
NSMutableArray *imagearray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image1.png",@"image2.png",@"image3.png", nil];
for(int i=0; i<[imagearray count]; i++)
{
    menubutton = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"menuBtn%d",i];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self valueForKey:menubutton];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imagearray objectAtIndex:i]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```